# Merge n DataFrames by TimeStamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, iot

I have a code that successfully merges for me 2 pandas dataframes using the

```
mergedDF = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="DateTime", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("7s"))
```

But, I want to merge a list of dataframes [df1, df2, , , dfn]. This list has sometimes 4 and sometimes 5 dataframes. Each dataframe has different columns, and only "DateTime" column is common between them.

I can do something like:

```
 mergedDF = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on="DateTime", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("7s"))
 mergedDF = pd.merge_asof(mergedDF, df3, on="DateTime", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("7s"))
 mergedDF = pd.merge_asof(mergedDF, df4, on="DateTime", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("7s"))
 mergedDF = pd.merge_asof(mergedDF, df5, on="DateTime", tolerance=pd.Timedelta("7s"))
```

However, with this I get only the timestamps of df1. Can anyone please throw ideas for me to lose as less data as possible?

Furthermore detail:
Timestamps of each row are 30 seconds away from the next row (on all dataframes). But df1 timestamps do not necessarily match df2, df3 or dfn timestamps. All are shifted in time.

Comment: Sadly merge_asof can only perform left-join like. Find in the doc : "For each row in the left DataFrame". Which is logic, since you try to match by distance. 

To sucessfully join all your data with minimal loss, you need to first find a way to match all your timestamps not pairwise but as a group, which can be extremelly difficult given that all dataframe are shifted.

Comment: I think I may not be playing fair with God's holy numbers I am sensing from a real-life physics machine, if I artificially shift (in time) all dataframe by x seconds to match df1 timestamps. I need something that gives me near equidistant resultant timestamps. One good thing is, the number of rows on all dataframes is close to same (28000 +50 rows or -50 rows).

Comment: I think, it's a good start. If all dataframe are coming from an automated device, then you can try to un-shift your datas, using some timeseries analysis (as a argmax of correlation if you have some common timeseries)